# Lexer and Parser rules for a simple command processor

Tags: antlr4

I am attempting to build a simple command processor for a legacy language.

I am attempting to work with C# with antlr4 version "ANTLR", "4.6.6")

I am unable to make progress against one scenario, of several.

The following examples shows various sample invocations of the command PKS.

```
PKS
```

```
PKS?
```

```
PKStext_that_is_a_filename
```

The scenario that I can not solve is the PKS command followed by filename.

```
Command:
PKS
(block (line (expr (command PKS)) (eol \r\n)) <EOF>)
Command:
PKS?
(block (line (expr (command PKS) (query ?)) (eol \r\n)) <EOF>)
Command:
PKSFILENAME
line 1:0 mismatched input 'PKSFILENAME' expecting COMMAND
(block PKSFILENAME \r\n)
Command:
```

what I believe to be the relevant snippet of grammar:

```
 block      : line+ EOF;
 line       : (expr eol)+;

 expr       : command file
            | command listOfDouble
            | command query
            | command
            ;

command     : COMMAND
            ;

query       : QUERY;
file        : TEXT ;
eol         : EOL;
listOfDouble: DOUBLE (COMMA DOUBLE)* ;
```

From the lexer:

```
COMMAND     : PKS;
PKS         :'PKS' ;

QUERY       : '?'
            ;

fragment LETTER : [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];
fragment UNDER  : [_];

TEXT        : (LETTER) (LETTER|DIGIT|UNDER)* ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that your `TEXT` rule also matches what `PKS` is supposed to match. And since `PKStext_that_is_a_filename` can entirely be matched by that `TEXT` rule it is preferred over the `PKS` rule, even though it appears first in the grammar (if 2 rules match the same input then the first one wins).

In order to fix that problem you have 2 options:

1. Require whitespace(s) between the keyword (PKS) and the rest of the expression.
2. Change the `TEXT` rule to explicitly exclude "PKS" as valid input.

Option 2 is certainly possible, but will get very messy if you have have more keywords (as they all would have to be excluded). With a whitespace between the keywords and the text the lexer would automatically do that for you.

And let me give you a hint to approach such kind of problems: always check the token list produced by the lexer to see if it generated the tokens you expected. I reworked your grammar a bit, added missing tokens and ran it through my ANTLR4 debugger, which gave me:

```
Parser error (5, 1): extraneous input 'PKStext_that_is_a_filename' expecting {<EOF>, COMMAND, EOL}

Tokens:
[@0,0:2='PKS',<1>,1:0]
[@1,3:3='\n',<8>,1:3]
[@2,4:4='\n',<8>,2:0]
[@3,5:7='PKS',<1>,3:0]
[@4,8:8='?',<3>,3:3]
[@5,9:9='\n',<8>,3:4]
[@6,10:10='\n',<8>,4:0]
[@7,11:36='PKStext_that_is_a_filename',<7>,5:0]
[@8,37:37='\n',<8>,5:26]
[@9,38:37='<EOF>',<-1>,6:0]
```

For this input:

```
PKS

PKS?

PKStext_that_is_a_filename
```

Here's the grammar I used:

```
grammar Example;

start: block;

block: line+ EOF;
line:  expr? eol;

expr: command (file | listOfDouble | query)?;

command: COMMAND;

query:        QUERY;
file:         TEXT;
eol:          EOL;
listOfDouble: DOUBLE (COMMA DOUBLE)*;

COMMAND: PKS;
PKS:     'PKS';

QUERY: '?';

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT:  [0-9];
fragment UNDER:  [_];

COMMA:  ',';
DOUBLE: DIGIT+ (DOT DIGIT*)?;
DOT:    '.';
TEXT:   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | UNDER)*;
EOL:    [\n\r];
```

and the generated visual parse tree:

[image]